# Expanding char by some more chars in C ( no overwriting allowed )

Tags: c, char

I would like to save more chars in `ch[500]` then it is already there. I dont want to lose the chars I've saved there before.

Something that would work like this:

```
ch = ch + ’nextch’;
```

Comment: Show us some code - how did you create and initialize the array? How did you insert the characters which are already there? Is it a zero terminated C string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) or `strncat()` to Concatenate two strings.

for example

```
char ch[100];
 strcpy(ch,"hello");
 strcat(ch," world");
```

if you want to append only one character

```
    char str[100];
    strcpy(str,"hello");
    char ch='a';

    char buf[2];
    sprintf(buf,"%c",ch); 
    strncat(str,sizeof str, buf);
```

or

```
    size_t length= strlen(str);
    str[strlen(str)]=ch;
    str[length+1]='\0';
```

Comment: Not sure, but if I understand the pseudo code in the question correctly, OP wants to append a **char** to the array, not a **string**

Comment: @Andreas you are correct. modified my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: You are counting two times with `strlen` in the last example